# Fill a polygon with a image opengl

Tags: c++, eclipse, image, opengl, textures

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/400b648e7442eeb3

You can read a piece of code: the idea is to fullfill a polygon quad with a texture ( the image is repeated inside the quad).

I want that the image would repeat only once: in other words to put the image as background of the polygon. Im in a 800x600 window, and i would like to put a billiards table for example 600x400 ( in a quad defined by the glvertex3i). It could be glvertex2i and implemented in 2D,as is a 2D game.

Any help would be apreciated

Also i have a better code to support any jpg file instead of loadtexture and readjpeg( i think):

```
GLuint MyLoadTexture(std::string const filename)
{
    GLuint texname = 0;
    /* this is actually tied to the OpenGL context, so this should
    * actually be a map GLcontext -> std::string -> texturename */
    static std::map<std::string, GLuint> loaded_textures;
    if( loaded_textures.find(filename) != loaded_textures.end() ) {
        texname = loaded_textures[filename];
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texname);
        return texname;
    }

    int width,height;
    std::vector<uint8_t> image;
    if( ReadJPEG(filename, &image, &width, &height) ) {
        std::cerr
            << "error reading JPEG"
            << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &texname);
    if( !texname ) {
        std::cerr
            << "error generating OpenGL texture name"
            << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texname);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);

   /* glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
        width, height, 0,
        GL_RGB,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );
    */
    glTexImage2D(
           GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
           width, height, 0,
           GL_RGB,
           GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &image[0]);

    loaded_textures[filename] = texname;

    return texname;
}

int ReadJPEG(
    std::string const filename,
    std::vector<uint8_t> *image,
    int *width, int *height )
{
     if( !image ) {
            return -1;
        }

        FILE * const infile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
        if( !infile ) {
            std::cerr
                << "error opening file "
                << filename
                << " : "
                << strerror(errno)
                << std::endl;
            return -2;
        }

        struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
        struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
        cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);

        jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

        jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);
        jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
        jpeg_calc_output_dimensions(&cinfo);
        jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

        if( width )  { *width  = cinfo.output_width;  }
        if( height ) { *height = cinfo.output_height; }

        size_t const stride = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components;
        image->resize(cinfo.output_height * stride);

        for(size_t i = 0; i < cinfo.output_height;) {
            uint8_t * const row =  &(*image)[stride * i];
            i += jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, (unsigned char**)&row, 1);
        }
        jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);

        fclose(infile);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code. The `ReadJPEG` does not actually help answer this question. Show your drawing code.

Comment: The example code is in coliru.. Is an example of repeating a texture in a quad. Update: Ive update coliru link to the concrete example ( pared.jpg is a n image with the texture, in this case a wall...)

Comment: Clamp your texture coordinates to the range 0.0...1.0. Also: you should be conscious that you are using highly obsolete OpenGL 2.0 API. It is a good idea to stop doing this and go for OpenGL 4 immediately.

Comment: I think the above code of LoadTexture and readjpeg are better than the ones in coliru ( more flexible). How can i do it ? Im afraid but going for opengl 4 is not an option by now....What advantages would i have if i change ?

Comment: It appears that by your code base you are using OpenGL v1.0. I would suggest scrapping this and start to learn modern OpenGL any version of OpenGL v3.3 or higher! Also reading in a jpeg is not friendly with OpenGL. You are better off using either TGA or preferably PNG, you could use a bmp but it does require a little bit of work.

Comment: A quad has 4 sides. A polygon has any number of sides greater than or equal to 3. So what is a "polygon quad"? Just a quad?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using a deprecated version of OpenGL. Now as for your situation, It is not obvious to me if you are concerned with alpha values within your textures or not. Also how many bytes does each color channel have? This is important to know.

In this section of your code there are a couple things that I see that should be improved:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texname);
if( !texname ) {
    std::cerr
        << "error generating OpenGL texture name"
        << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texname);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);

/* glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
    width, height, 0,
    GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );
*/
glTexImage2D(
       GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
       width, height, 0,
       GL_RGB,
       GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &image[0]);

loaded_textures[filename] = texname;
```

Before you call `glGenTextures(1, &texname);` you should call this first:

```
glGetError(); // This will clear errors
```

After your call to `glGenTextures(1, &texname);`instead of checking texname for errors this method is preferred:

```
GLenum err = glGetError();
if ( err != GL_NO_ERROR ) {
    // Generate Error Here, either log message to file, console or throw an error
}
```

Next is your `glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texname );` which is good. Now as for OpenGL's functions that generate and bind the textures the second parameter is an unsigned ID that OpenGL generates automatically that associates it with the filename that it is given. It is easier for a machine to read an unsigned value to check for multiple resources than it is to check and verify a string. It is also a performance increase when an application is working 100s, 1000s or even 1,000,000s of resource files.

After this you are now setting up the parameters on how OpenGL will deal with mipmaps. And this section of your code appears to be fine if this is the behavior you want for mipmapping. However the caller to this function for using a texture has no method to set the quality level of a mipmap. What I normally do here is have an enumeration that deals with the different quality levels of mimpmaps here is snippet of how I handle working with mipmaps:

Note: the enum value is not defined or declared within this function it would be a parameter that would be passed to it.

```
// This enum I usually have it declared or defined in a CommonStructs header.
enum FilterQuality {
    FILTER_NONE = 1,
    FILTER_GOOD,
    FILTER_BETTER,
    FILTER_BEST
 }; // FilterQuality

 // Now as within side of my function for generating texture files I have something like this for mipmaps:     
if ( texture.generateMipMap ) {
    switch ( texture.filterQuality ) {
        case TextureInfo::FILTER_NONE : {
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
            break;
        }
        case TextureInfo::FILTER_GOOD: {
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
            break;
        }
        case TextureInfo::FILTER_BEST: {
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
            break;
        }
        default: {
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
        }
    } // Switch

    if ( openglVersion.x < 3 ) {
        // In OpenGL v3 GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP Is Deprecated, And In 3.1+ It Was Removed
        // So For Those Versions We Use glGenerateMipmap below
        static const unsigned int GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP = 0x8191;
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE );
    }
} else { // No MipMaps
    switch( texture.filterQuality ) {
        case TextureInfo::FILTER_NONE:
        case TextureInfo::FILTER_GOOD: {
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
            break;
        }
        default: {
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        }
    } 
}
```

The only thing that I see that could be irrelevant is your call to `glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_REPLACE);` for I have never used it, now this may be some type of behavior that you want and for that I do not know.

After you set up your mimpmapping information this is where you want to set the parameters for clamping or wrap repeat which you are missing from your code to generate a texture. They look like this:

```
bool wrapRepeat; // This variable would not be here inside of the function,
// but would come from this function's definition so that the caller can
// set this parameter or flag to the behavior they want for each texture in use.

// What these two lines of code will do depending on the state of wrapRepeat
// is they will cause the last parameter to be either WRAP in S & T coordinates or
// to clamp to edge in both S & T coordinates.
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, (wrapRepeat ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE ) );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, (wrapRepeat ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE ) );
```

Finally you have your code that will load the texture into memory and as a reference this is what I have within my function to generate textures:

```
// Load Texture Into Video Memory
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, texture.hasAlphaChannel ? 4 : 1 );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    ( texture.hasAlphaChannel ? GL_RGBA8 : GL_RGB8 ),
    texture.uWidth,
    texture.uHeight,
    0,
    ( texture.hasAlphaChannel ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB ),
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    &texture.vPixelData[0] );

if ( texture.generateMipMap && openglVersion.x >= 3 ) {
    glGenerateMipmap( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
}
```

This should help you to resolve your current problem with your textures being wrapped and not clamped.

Now as for my project, I have a derived filehandler class that reads in texture files specifically and it loads in either a TGA or a PNG file and the way that it is designed it can load in any other texture or image file as long as you add a function to that class to parse the file type. My actual image types used in rendering are separate from the file reader. And they are separate from this code here. This code belongs to a class that is an AssetStorage. This class of mine is responsible for storing all assets and managing their memory and that is it. This class does not render anything, but it does load objects into ram and video ram. It is my batch class and batch manager classes that handles all of the rendering of objects. Now my objects are all built off of using GLSL Shaders. But to show you this function in full can be used as a reference into how my framework is designed.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// add()
// Creates An OpenGL Texture And Returns It's ID Value
// This Can Only Be Called From The Main OpenGL Thread
TextureInfo AssetStorage::add( const Texture& texture, const std::string& strFilename ) {
    if ( INVALID_UNSIGNED != getTextureInfo( strFilename ).uTextureId ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " can not store " << strFilename << " multiple times";
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    TextureInfo textureInfo;
    textureInfo.hasTransparency = texture.hasAlphaChannel;
    textureInfo.size = glm::uvec2( texture.uWidth, texture.uHeight );

    glGetError(); // Clear Errors

    glGenTextures( 1, &textureInfo.uTextureId );

    GLenum err = glGetError();
    if ( err != GL_NO_ERROR ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed glGenTextures with error code 0x" << std::hex << err;
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureInfo.uTextureId );

    // Wrap Textures
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, ( texture.wrapRepeat ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE ) );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, ( texture.wrapRepeat ? GL_REPEAT : GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE ) );

    const glm::uvec2& openglVersion = s_pSettings->getOpenglVersion();

    if ( texture.generateMipMap ) {
        switch ( texture.filterQuality ) {
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_NONE : {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
                break;
            }
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_GOOD: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
                break;
            }
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_BEST: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
            }
        } // Switch

        if ( openglVersion.x < 3 ) {
            // In OpenGL v3 GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP Is Deprecated, And In 3.1+ It Was Removed
            // So For Those Versions We Use glGenerateMipmap below
            static const unsigned int GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP = 0x8191;
            glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE );
        }
    } else { // No MipMaps
        switch( texture.filterQuality ) {
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_NONE:
            case TextureInfo::FILTER_GOOD: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
                glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
            }
        } 
    }

    // Load Texture Into Video Memory
    glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, texture.hasAlphaChannel ? 4 : 1 );
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        ( texture.hasAlphaChannel ? GL_RGBA8 : GL_RGB8 ),
        texture.uWidth,
        texture.uHeight,
        0,
        ( texture.hasAlphaChannel ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB ),
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        &texture.vPixelData[0] );

    if ( texture.generateMipMap && openglVersion.x >= 3 ) {
        glGenerateMipmap( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    }

    // Store TextureId
    BlockThread blockThread( s_criticalSection );
    m_textureInfos.insert( MapTextureInfos::value_type( strFilename, textureInfo ) );

    if ( s_pSettings->isDebugLoggingEnabled( Settings::DEBUG_MEMORY ) ) {
        Logger::log( std::string( "Created " ) + strFilename );
    }

    return textureInfo;
} // add
```

Comment: Can you edit it in coliru please ? It would be nice to have an example of use..http://cnilove.com/pool-table-top/perfect-pool-table-top-for-home-decoration-ideas-with-pool-table-top/ as background...an i want to use it in a quad fo width, height dimensions.. I assume you are using the functions ( loadtexture and readjpege) "improved" shown above.. and not the other used in coliru. Thanks for your help. Its not imporant bytes of color or alpha, alpha i use always 0 ( i think)... I only need to show the billiards table inside the quad... Then i have to add the balls etc...

Comment: Also its not necessary to use this method, if theres something easier.. the idea is that in a window for example 800x600 i could add black colour as glClearColor and then put the billards table in for example 400x300 ( letting the borders black). thanks for your help...

Comment: @EduardoGutiérrez There is a difference between applying a material (color) to a polygon as opposed to applying a texture.

Comment: @EduardoGutiérrez Basically you would still want to create triangle strips. You would have to define 2 triangles and have their vertices defined in the right winding order. This would be in your Image2d class.

Comment: @EduardoGutiérrez I'm not at all familiar with coliru. I can suggest a great website that has a few series of video tutorials that deals with OpenGL and 3D Game Engine development. Visit http://www.MarekKnows.com His first series of tutorials OpenGL Game Engine covers OpenGL v1.0 in full detail on how to create different shapes, to apply materials and textures to them, how to define your vertices, indexes, and UV coordinates. It also shows how to create lighting. Then his next series is a combo of OpenGL Tips & Tricks and Physics Engine. Then we use that to make a 3D Game in Ghost Toast...

Comment: @EduardoGutiérrez Finally, his newest series goes into working with Modern OpenGL and that is the Shader Engine.

Comment: @EduardoGutiérrez The code that I provided above only shows you how to load textures into memory, and how you want it configured such as using MipMaps and if you want to WrapRepeat or to Clamp to Edge. The code that applies this pixel color information is not here, it is usually found in your objects that you create to be rendered.

Comment: @EduardoGutiérrez and you should worry about alpha values, let say you have a graphic image and the pool table you want to apply to your rectangle has rounded corners, and on the outside of those corners the image has an alpha channel (transparency). If you don't tell OpenGL to use alpha, then these pixels could render in either black or white, and will not show any color information or background colors (textures) that are behind this image.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.Coliru is just an editor where you can edit and then in terminal compile a program, and then share it like paste bin. I would follow your suggestions and try, but the example was working well. Its good to improve the code. But what im trying is how to put the billieard table ( example the link i pass to you or another) as background in a quad defined. I need to start putting in the balls and the movements, and im stuck on inserting and show the image. As i told you if you know any alternative to achieve this Perhaps we can chat or hangouts. Thanks again

Comment: sorry but you know how to put an image es background in opengl ? Ideally a quad inside a window, but could the whole window also...Thanks